# Web API post method without parameter in URL(Login parameter)

Tags: c#, url, methods, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am passing login parameter using post method in WebAPI from body part. I want to hide these parameters(`Username`, `Password`) in the URL(`http: //localhost:3069/api/Login?username=admin&password=123`) but I only want `url(http://localhost:3069/api/Login)`.

```
using SMSWebAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace SMSWebAPI.Controllers {
    /// <summary>
    /// for login post api
    /// </summary>
    [RoutePrefix("api/Login")]
    public class LoginController: ApiController {
        private SMSApiEntities db = new SMSApiEntities();

        [HttpPost][Route("")]

        public IQueryable < object > Login(string username, string password) {
            var obj = (from p in db.UserLogins
            where p.LoginId == username && p.Password == password
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
            return db.UserLogins.Where(i = >i.LoginId.Equals(username) && i.Password.Equals(password));
        }
    }
}

expected result - http: //localhost:3069/api/Login
actual result - http: //localhost:3069/api/Login?username=admin&password=123
```

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api ?

Comment: using postman by selecting post method I am passing this url(http://localhost:3069/api/Login) and sending the parameter from body part {
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123"
} but it showing the output {
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://coeindia.in/test/WebApi/api/Login'."
}

Comment: that looks like its sent using get not post to have the variables on the uri

Comment: @vishalsharma https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the Login Model and Also add the [FromBody] before the argument. So according to the Current Scenario, your model would be.

```
public class LoginUser
{
    //Using Pascal Case for Properties
    public string Username { get; set; } 
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And the function would be

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<object> Login([FromBody] LoginUser UserCredentails)
{
   return db.UserLogins.Where(i => i.LoginId.Equals(UserCredentails.Username) && i.Password.Equals(password)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a new class:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `[FromBody]` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<object> Login([FromBody] Model myModel)
{
    //Access properties here: myModel.Username
}
```

After that you can send them in the body of your request and then web api will receive them with model binder.